# Magento 2: How to Banned some words to be used by products and customer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have around 500 words which I want to banned them to be use on product add and user registration. How can i do that ?

I tried using the event and observer for catalog_product_save_after

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="ghrix_bannedwords_banned" instance="Ghrix\BannedWords\Observer\Banned"  />
    </event> 
</config>
```

any other way to do globally ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you can use `catalog_product_save_before` event instead of `catalog_product_save_after`.If you define your events.xml at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc` location  then it is  fire for all  area.

#### For all save

Yes, you can do global using `model_save_before`  event and `entity_manager_save_before` which is a fire during all data save  using model and  repository save

Comment: can't we do globally ? so that it will work for customers too

Comment: what you mean by globally?

Comment: globally in the sense, for any type of data save (whether customer or products) it will show error for banned words